# How to know the position of the character?

Tags: c++, qt

How to find the first occurrence of a character from the end, but at the same time indicate the position of the end of the string at which to look for?
Ie we need the following function.

```
lastIndexOf(char c, int position_from_end);
```

As will be:

```
QString s("abcadc");
int i = s.mylastIndexOf('c', 0) //6
```

.

```
QString s1("abcadc");
int j = s1.mylastIndexOf('c', 1) //3
```

Comment: iterate from `position_from_end` toward 0 and check if any char matches `c`?

Comment: @yejep The function you showed does not deal with any string.

Comment: If the questions is about Qt, than `QString::lastIndexOf()`

Comment: @Andro47 Please don't change the OP's code. It's part of the question.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I think OP probably meant that they need the *method* indicated, so that the string would be the `this` object.

Comment: @yejep Forgot to say welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry it was kinda not-so-smooth. Next time it should go a little better for ya. = P

Answer (score 1):

In c++, use the `std::string` method `rfind(char c, size_t pos)`

The character will be searched for in the part of the string which comes before index `pos`. (If you were to use the version of `rfind` which searches for a substring, the *first character* of the match must come before `pos`).

`pos` defaults to `string::npos`, which is larger than any valid string index and therefore causes the search to start at the end of the string.

It returns `string::npos` if no match is found.

If you want to specify the offset from the end of the string, you can subtract the offset from the string's length:

```
std::string s;
//...
size_t p = s.rfind(ch, s.size() - offset);
```

Comment: @yejep: I really don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: yejep's question asks about `QString`, not `std::string`.

Comment: @KubaOber: But the `QString` answer is in the question, no?

Comment: Not quite - there is no method matching the signature he wishes for. The solution is trivial: pass a `QChar` constructed from `char`.

Comment: @KubaOber: Is there not an implicit conversion to QChar from char? Anyway, do feel free to provide an answer.